# opencv error Assertion failed

Tags: opencv

OpenCV Error:

```
 Assertion failed (scaleFactor > 1 && image.depth() == CV_8U) in detectMultiScale, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.9+dfsg/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp, line 1081
    terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
      what():  /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.9+dfsg/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp:1081: error: (-215) scaleFactor > 1 && image.depth() == CV_8U in function detectMultiScale.
```

Why does this error happen?

Comment: either your scale factor is < 1 or your input image isnt of type 8UC1 (maybe it is a color image)? please post your functipn call code and your image input call

Comment: err: single channel might not be necessary... but deptj must be 8 bit, so no floating point image for example

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [cascade classifier detectMultiScale documentation.](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#cascadeclassifier-detectmultiscale)

```
void CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale(const Mat& image, vector<Rect>& objects, double scaleFactor=1.1, int minNeighbors=3, int flags=0, Size minSize=Size(), Size maxSize=Size())
```

for **image** it states:

> Matrix of the type **CV_8U** containing an image where objects are
>   detected

for **scaleFactor** it states:

> Parameter specifying how much the image size is ***reduced*** at each image scale.

If you understand how cascade classifiers work you'll note having a scaleFactor below zero isn't going to do anything useful.

The assertion is trying to tell you what you need, so read it backwards - it failed as:

```
 (scaleFactor > 1 && image.depth() == CV_8U)
```

...returned '0' - as we are using a boolean AND, this means either one or both of the logical statements failed... (as such there are three possibilities)